# AbstractMethodError in Spring

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, logback

I'm trying to store data with H2 and hibernate in my Spring project,
and i cant get rid of this:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:187)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
```

my pom file:

http://pastebin.com/hxXyZi9b

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Spring references documentation:

> A common choice might be to bridge Spring to SLF4J, and then provide explicit binding from SLF4J to
>   Log4J. You need to supply 4 dependencies (and exclude the existing commons-logging): the bridge,
>   the SLF4J API, the binding to Log4J, and the Log4J implementation itself. In Maven you would do that
>   like this

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, i replaced my logging dependencies with this, but i still got the same error

Answer (score 1):

There must be version mismatch between your mentioned slf4j dependencies and slf4j lib used spring-core in pom.xml.

If you are using eclipse, you can easily check(by searching) in Depedency Hierarchy tab in pom.xml.